# iOS: GCDAsyncSocket and its tag

Tags: ios, asyncsocket, gcdasyncsocket

In my app I'm using GCDAsyncSocket and I write and read in this way:

```
NSData *bufferWriteData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bufferWrite length:17 freeWhenDone:YES];
[self.socket writeData:bufferWriteData withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
[self.socket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:1];
```

after I read in the delegate method the data:

```
- (void) socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag{

    NSLog(@"did read data");

    if (tag == 1){

       //analyze my data...

       [self.socket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:1];
    }
```

inside this delegate method I recall the "readDataWithTimeout" so in this way I read all data.

The problem id when I do a new call, if I do:

```
[self.socket writeData:bufferWriteData withTimeout:-1 tag:2];
[self.socket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:2];
```

I start a new write and a new read with tag = 2; 
When the delegate method "didReadData" is called my code enter inside the block of tag = 1; it seems that it don't recognize the new tag.

Why it happen?

Comment: There is no relationship between the tags value of writing and reading.

Comment: ok and what's the way to manage the different reader?

Comment: When send data, you should tell peer when data ends by adding a header in front of the data. In the header, there should be a length field which indicate the length of data and a id field which indicate the index of data. The id field works as the tag in your code, but it need the server send response with the same id.

Comment: can make me an example please? It seems that if I have an open "readData" in the delegate method "didRead" it continue to work until arrive some data to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to handle this.  In your case, the best way probably just used a terminator to indicate the end of that data segment.  You can read up there:  [TCP is a stream.](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/wiki/CommonPitfalls)

```
NSData *MyCommandTerminator(void)
{
    return [NSData dataWithBytes:"\x0D\x0A\x0B\x0A" length:4];
}

//callback from Asyncsocket for incoming data
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag  //sender and receiver
{
    NSLog(@"GCDAsyncSocket didreaddata");
    // do what you wish with data and read again using a terminator
    [sock readDataToData:MyCommandTerminator() withTimeout:-1 tag:1];   //tag is not being used here
}

// your method to send data
-(void)sendData:(NSData *)data
{
        // NSData *bufferWriteData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bufferWrite length:17 freeWhenDone:YES];
        NSLog(@"Sendata wehere _peerSocket is your instance of GCDAsyncSocket");
        NSMutableData *myData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data];
        [myData appendData:MyCommandTerminator()];
        [_peerSocket writeData:myData withTimeout:-1 tag:2];   // tag is not being used here
    }
```